# Copper sweating to heat pump

Tags: heat-pump, copper, solder

Yesterday I got a brand new heat pump. Long story short, it was messy at best. In particular, the copper sweating attached to the condenser unit seems problematic in a couple of ways. First, copper that has been out in the coastal salt air for 20-years was reused. I've had issues with that very line in the past as it took a lot of corrosion from the air. The second thing that is concerning is the seemingly incompatible pipes sweated together with a bunch of solder.

Is this a concerning item from the standpoint of having future issues with the system, or is it just little more than ugly?

[image: Heat Pump Copper]

Comment: Well, wouldn't be anything I would expect or accept. Looks like you hired the lowest bid and got exactly what you paid for...

Comment: Why do you think the pipes are incompatible?  Looks to me likes it's copper to brass, which I think is fine.

Comment: And, you probably didn't pay to have the refrigerant lines replaced.  That is, I bet that work was not part of your contract.

Comment: @SteveSh  The pipe on top seems to be two different sizes without using a reducer.

Comment: Those scorch marks on the right make it look like the installer didn't even shield the adjacent area from the flame! I'd guess they probably also didn't use a heat sink to make sure heat wasn't conducted along the piping to the unit, possibly damaging plastic/rubber seals and parts there. Hopefully the worst case is just that it stops working someday...

Comment: @crip659 - You may be right.  If so, and the joint is being mechanically held together with solder, it needs to be redone, properly.

Comment: @keshlam I did not hire the lowest bid. I used a company that has been great up until now. Turns out that one of the main guys is partially retired. Also, I live in Florida, where small government means good luck on getting any work done. Really could use some unions around here.

Comment: You all have hit on the concerns I have. I just spoke with the business owner and he vehemently apologized and says that it will all be made right.

Comment: If the owner stands behind the work, you have a good one.   Giving him a coffee and a cookie would not be out of line if the repairs are good.

Comment: Sorry you got to be the one who discovered that the firm's new hire wasn't competent; glad they are making it right. A bit disappointed they didn't have one of their established staff checking the new guy's work; too many customers would have assumed it had to be this way.

Comment: i thought my soldering looked bad - that's something else !

Answer (score 1):

There is damage on the adjacent unit, with burn marks.

Who is to replace that?

Since no proper pipe reducer was used, there is very large amount of solder in there.

I would be concerned how much of it is actually blocking the pipe by flowing in there.

Remove, replace and redo.

Comment: And, what's more, use a pro.  Code requires that only licensed individuals work on HVAC systems, and have equipment and supply relationships to recycle the refrigerant.  (unless they use one of about a half dozen refrigerants exempt from this rule).  A guy who solders like that is probably "handyman tier" and is not handling the refrigerant properly.